# "The site's security certificate is not trusted!" on every SSL page?

Tags: macos, google-chrome

I'm using the latest Chrome dev build on Mac OS X. Recently, I've been getting this message on *any* HTTPS webpage when I visit it the first time:

> **The site's security certificate is not trusted!**
>   You attempted to reach checkout.google.com, but the server presented a certificate issued by an entity that is not trusted by your computer's operating system. This may mean that the server has generated its own security credentials, which Google Chrome cannot rely on for identity information, or an attacker may be trying to intercept your communications. You should not proceed, especially if you have never seen this warning before for this site.

Why is this here, and how can I fix it? It may be because of my development build, but many other people use the dev version also, and I expect it would be fixed quicker then this.

Comment: It could be you're being hacked, and someone is intercepting all your HTTPS traffic. Does it affect other browsers or only Chrome?

Comment: Only  ``  Chrome. ``

Comment: Same problem over here, only on Chrome.

Comment: Now problem has gone away. You?

Comment: @Yar - problem has also gone away for me.

Comment: I have the same problem and my datetime is correct. Still stuck in this error.

Comment: How did the problem go away? Please elaborate.

Answer (score 4):

What's the date and time set to on your computer? If it's significantly behind or ahead then certificates will fail validation as being not yet valid or expired.

You may also want to check that you have the latest trusted root certificates installed.

Comment: good idea, a big date mismatch could be the cause.

Comment: I'm at the right date and time. How can I check the root certificates?

Comment: I'm not sure on a Mac, but I believe Apple released updates a while ago for the root certificate authorities. Since you say it's only `Chrome` above, my suggestions above probably won't help. Can you see if Chrome has a certification path display similar to what IE allows? http://www.carbonwind.net/ISA/ACaseofMITM/Fiddler%20Certificate%20Certification%20Path.jpg

Answer (score 1):

Check your BIOS / CMOS watch battery
It needs to be replaced most likely

Answer (score 1):

I don't know anything about Chrome internals, but it seems to me like you may not have any certificate authorities loaded.

Certificates work as a hierarchy of trust.  If I trust a certificate, I trust all the certificates the trusted certificate has signed.  However, I need to trust something in order to start this chain.

Browsers normally contain certificates from certificate authorities the browser supplier thinks you should trust (like Verisign, for example), and browsers normally flag certificates that don't inherit from one of those pre-approved certificates as untrusted.

Since you're using a dev build, it's likely that nobody made sure there would be certificates pre-loaded.  Check your instructions to see if you missed a step involving certificates, or check the Chrome site to see if there's a certificate file.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to access various secure web sites without encountering this error. I've tested Mac Snow Leopard / Google Chrome (4.0.249.49 (35163) beta).

Perhaps the issue is related to the dev version?

Answer (score -1):

The site may have a self-generated security certificate.  This can be common for smaller sites, especially if they have a small user base.  These aren't registered with any of the verification sites and can generate this warning every time you try to load one of their pages.  I'm not familiar with Chrome, but Firefox prompts you to see if you want to access the site and also allows you to accept the certificate permanently.  If you trust the site, you probably want to do this.

Comment: He says it affects all sites he visits.

Comment: @taspeotis:  Oops!  I missed that.  Do you really think it was worth a downvote?

Comment: Not reading the question? Yes.

Comment: @taspeotis:  Apparently you didn't read my earlier comment.  I did read the question, but missed the "any".  Also, the OP doesn't say how many or what web sites he's visited, if it's a small number of sites, I don't think it's unreasonable to think he might have only encountered the sort of sites I described.

Comment: I won't downvote you but I should. Please delete this totally irrelevant answer.